# Logs in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I want to know that why audit,auditlog and history logs files are being used as i din't find anything in these files in my system.

Can anybody help me to understand the usage of these log files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those three log files (`audit.log`, `auditlog.log` and `history.log`) are default AEM log files that are created out of the box when you start an AEM instance.

### audit.log

This log file is used by JackRabbit to log changes to the repository. By default this log file is set to log level `info`. As far as I can tell there is not much logging going on at this level. Because of that your `audit.log` seems to be empty. If you set this log file to log level `debug` you will see log messages every time you make changes to the repository. For example if you add a component to a page, delete a page etc.

Example log entry:

> 09.04.2017 15:38:58.429 [admin] [session-2076087] Adding node [/content/myproject/mypage/jcr:content/parsys/mycomponent]

Here I added the component `mycomponent` to the page `mypage`. It will also log every property that was added to such a node etc.

### auditlog.log

I was not able to find any information about this log file. As far as I can tell this log file logs messages for classes of this package `com.adobe.granite.audit`. Even setting the log level of this logger to `debug` did not create any messages.

### history.log

This log file will contain high level logs about the things your editors do. It will for example log if a editor views or edits a page:

> 09.04.2017 15:38:36 VIEW admin [/content/myproject/mypage] [cq:Page]
>
> 09.04.2017 15:38:58 EDIT admin [/content/myproject/mypage] [cq:Page]

This log is probably only relevant on *author* instances.